# how to select multiple objects with mouse in tkinter python gui?

Tags: user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to select multiple objects using mouse just like in windows click and drag. i am using tkinter in python to buils this gui. i am creating objects as shown in below code.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
w= Canvas(root, width=800, height=768)
w.grid()
w.create_line(200,200,300,300, width=3, tags="line1")
w.create_oval(150,100,170,300, fill="red", tags="oval")

mainloop()
```

what i am trying to do is if i drag my mouse over multiple objects some def should return the tags of the objects. how can i do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Save the coordinates on a button-down event, and then on a button-up event use the [find_enclosed](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_enclosed-method) or [find_overlapping](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) method of the canvas to find all items enclosed by the region.

Answer (score 0):

The following code renders a rectangle that follows the cursor and returns a list of element IDs of elements within the rectangle.  It uses bindings for when the mouse is pressed within the canvas, when it moves, and when it is released.  I then kept a list of elements with their canvas identifier and used that to back lookup the object from the list of selected IDs.

```
# used to record where dragging from
originx,originy = 0,0

canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", __SelectStart__)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", __SelectMotion__)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", __SelectRelease__)

# binding for drag select
def __SelectStart__(self, event):
    oiginx = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    originy = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    selectBox = canvas.create_rectangle(originx,originy,\
        originx,originy)

# binding for drag select
def __SelectMotion__(self, event):
    xnew = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    ynew = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    # correct cordinates so it gives (upper left, lower right)
    if xnew < x and ynew < y:
        canvas.coords(selectBox,xnew,ynew,originx,originy)
    elif xnew < x:
        canvas.coords(selectBox,xnew,originy,originx,ynew)
    elif ynew < y:
        canvas.coords(selectBox,originx,ynew,xnew,originy)
    else:
        canvas.coords(selectBox,originx,originy,xnew,ynew)

# binding for drag select
def __SelectRelease__(self, event):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = canvas.coords(selectBox)
    canvas.delete(selectBox)
    # find all objects within select box
    selectedPointers = []
    for i in canvas.find_withtag("tag"):
        x3,y3,x4,y4 = canvas.coords(i)
        if x3>x1 and x4<x2 and y3>y1 and y4<y2:
            selectedPointers.append(i)
    Callback(selectedPointers)

# function to receive IDs of selected items
def Callback(pointers):
    print(pointers)
```